# Consolidating Windows 8 Search to one Textbox

Tags: windows, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to show all Windows 8 Modern UI search results on one page?](https://superuser.com/questions/434615/is-there-a-way-to-show-all-windows-8-modern-ui-search-results-on-one-page)

As many of you guy recall, in Windows 7 pressing Win and then typing yielded instant search results regardless of what type of search you were trying to perform (i. e. Apps, Settings, Files). In Windows 8, MS decided to differentiate between those three searches with 3 different text boxes; this is quite annoying. I used to be able to press Win and then start tying "system" to get the corresponding settings option; now I have to manually select Settings and then type.

Is there any way to consolidate this to one search bar, like in Windows 7? Currently, this (along with the non-evident power button) is one of the only real complaints I have about Windows 8.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: If there isn't, it's a good reason to make a small utility.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's impossible. However, WinKey+F searches for files and WinKey+W searches for settings.