# Search all or search files as default in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to show all Windows 8 Modern UI search results on one page?](https://superuser.com/questions/434615/is-there-a-way-to-show-all-windows-8-modern-ui-search-results-on-one-page)

In Windows 7, **Win key + [search term]** would return both applications and files. In Windows 8, the same key combination will only return applications by default. You have to explicitly choose to search either one, with **Win + F** to search for files.

My first question is: Is it possible to get back the Windows 7 behaviour of searching both applications and files simultaneously in Windows 8? (Doesn't seem that far off, considering Windows 8 is anyway counting up results in the other category while searching for one.)

My second question is: Is it possible to make Windows 8 search files by default when just pressing the Windows key?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to show all Windows 8 Modern UI search results on one page?](http://superuser.com/questions/434615/is-there-a-way-to-show-all-windows-8-modern-ui-search-results-on-one-page), [Consolidating Windows 8 Search to one Textbox](http://superuser.com/questions/484168/consolidating-windows-8-search-to-one-textbox), [Combine Windows 8 app and settings search?](http://superuser.com/questions/498057/combine-windows-8-app-and-settings-search) etc.